# How do I enable access log for load balancer using ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService cdk construct

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have tried this, but the access log is not enabling for Application Load Balancer created by **ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService** high-level construct.

```
// Creating S3 bucket for LoadBalancer Logs
const lbLogs = new s3.Bucket(this, 'S3labxLBaccessLogs');

const loadBalancedService = new ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(this, 'LogicalID, {
      cluster: cluster, // Required
      cpu: 512, // Default is 256
      desiredCount: 1, // Default is 1
      taskImageOptions: { 
        image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromRegistry('image'),
        },
      memoryLimitMiB: 1024, // Default is 512
      certificate: certificate,
      domainName: domainName,
      domainZone: hostedZone,
      assignPublicIp: true
    });

loadBalancedService.loadBalancer.logAccessLogs(lbLogs, 'microservice-logs');
```

Any workaround for this?

Comment: This worked for me, but it failed initially because my S3 bucket name was too long. CDK swallowed the error. However, I discovered it when I tried to use `setAttribute` to enable logging and add the bucket. Then I shortened the bucket name and everything worked well.